# How to require the user to click a button before submitting?

Tags: java, jbutton

I am making a star rating system

There are 5 buttons in a frame

If the user clicks the first button, add 1 to the rating
If the user clicks the second button, add 2 to the rating, and so on

but if the user clicks submit before pressing any button the rating will be zero

I want to make that each user has to rate, before the leave.

I read that that JButton have the method isPressed() , but i don't have it in my netbeans?

i think that is all, thank you so much if you are willing to help, sorry for my english btw!

Comment: Disable the submit button by default and enable it on click of any rating button.

Comment: what do you mean you dont have it on your netbeans? isnt netbeans an IDE? you can still use this method, sometimes IDE's have shenanigans

Comment: If you hand code your Swing GUI, and don't rely on a GUI builder, then you can modify the code yourself to enable or disable JBUttons.

Comment: Tank You! You guys are number one!